# Pfsense with WAN (NIC 1) and routing between two networks(NIC 2 and 3)

Tags: router, ethernet, internet, pfsense, pfsense-2

I have a server with three NICs running PfSense. The first NIC connects to my ISP, the second NIC connects to local computers in my office (LAN-1). For the third NIC(LAN-2), i have connected it to a computer and i want it to be able to connect to the second NIC(LAN-1) as well as the first(WAN).

**NIC 1 = gateway  = WAN
NIC 2 = LAN-1   = 172.30.0.3/16
NIC 3 = LAN-2   = 172.40.0.3/16**

Problem is that is that i can ping LAN-2(172.40.0.3)  from LAN-1(172.30.0.0/16)  but i cannot ping or trace anything from LAN-2 to LAN-1, or even to the internet. When i ping from LAN-2, there is no reply, not even a timeout.. it stays blank till i disconnect and it give an destination host unreachable message.

The pfsense version is 2.2.3-RELEASE (amd64)

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall seems to consider your LAN-1 as Inside, and LAN-2 as Outside.  You need to fix the firewall rules.

While you are at it, double-check that the WAN connection is an Outside connection.

Answer (score 1):

By default pfSense doesn't add any rules for the Interfaces other than WAN and LAN, so LAN-2 which is probably (at least originally) OPT1 in pfsense doesn't have any rules.

Go to Rules and select the interface and add an appropriate rule (ICMP to allow ping to work and and other rules that are necessary for the PC on that interface.

Comment: this was helpful...